# Cors origin error on my js code Please help me. How can I fix this

Tags: php, jquery

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.elitedias.com/checkid' from origin 'https://stag.speedyninja.co' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. VM5836:50  POST https://api.elitedias.com/checkid net::ERR_FAILED 403 (FORBIDDEN)`

Cors origin error on my js code Please help me. How can I fix this.

Answer (score -1):

```html
Try this in the .htaccess of the external root folder :

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have already defined in .htaccess file https://prnt.sc/GC9UZ1Ucgbsf but not working